# Using Connection manager in script task in ssis 2008

Tags: ssis

I have made ssis package where in I have taken Script task and by using that script task I am taking count from one of the Database table and sending that count in mail. Now,in that script task,if I take connection from variable ,it works. But I want to take connection directly from connection manager but it is not working. Please suggest on the same.Below is code snippet I have used.

```
    Public Sub Main()
    Dim str_con As String
    str_con = Dts.Connections("INPUND79.Sample.sample").ConnectionString.ToString()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(str_con)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select count(*) from Department", con)
    Dim a As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Dim message As String = "Total Number of Records in Department Table is :" & a & ""
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    SmtpServer.Host = "UKCAMSCAS10.aveva.com"
    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("mandar.dandage@aveva.com")
    mail.To.Add("mandar.dandage@aveva.com")
    mail.Subject = "Count in Table"
    mail.Body = message
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Guys,
This problem has been resolved now . I used OleDbConnection,OleDbCommand instead of SQlConnection and SQLCommand respectvely. Because my connection Manager is of type OleDBConnection. :) ..That solved the issue.Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've answered your question; however, this is not the best way to do it because you're now using a separate connection, for example it won't be affected if you are using transactions in the package. You should use the below script for **OLE DB** connections:

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["INPUND79.Sample.sample"];
IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
connection = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;
// Do whatever you want with the connection
cm.ReleaseConnection(connection);
```

This is the proper way to do it.
You should reference **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll"**.